# Existence of the limit of $f(x)$ given that $\lim (g(x)-h(x)) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

I'm trying to determine whether the following statement is true:

> If $f,g,h: X \to \mathbb{R}$ are maps from a metric space $X$ into $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) \leq g(x) \leq h(x)$ for all values $x \in X$ except possibly at some $a \in X$, and if $\lim_{x \to a}\left(g(x)-h(x)\right) = 0$, then $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ exists.

So this implies that $g$ and $h$ have the same limit at $x = a$, I think. However this doesn't necessarily mean that they are the same function.

Other than that I'm not sure how to prove or disprove the existence of a limit of $f$ at $a$. Am I right in saying that the limit only exists when it is also equal to that of $g$ and $h$ (i.e. $f(a)=g(a)=h(a)$), since $f(x)$ is bounded above by $g(x)$ and $h(x)$?

Pardon my ignorance, Analysis is very much not my thing.

Thanks.

Comment: No it's not necessary , F(a) may be very less than H(a) and still be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true:

Let $X=\Bbb R,\ a=0,\ f(x)=\mathrm{sgn}(x), \ g(x)=h(x)=1$.